# Can Perl handle this OOP concept - Explained in Animal Terms

Tags: perl, class, oop, subclass, superclass

Sorry for being very vague but I do not know the name of the concept.  I will try to explain.  I'll try to put it in terms of animals to make it easy.

I have a generic superclass.  This superclass contains functions that all animals have to do.  For example I do not want to redefine "take_breath" sub in every animal subclass, so I define it once inside the Animals superclass and all of the animals (Animals::Cat, Animals::Dog, and Animals::Llama) can simply access $self->take_breath().  The animals also go through many of the same initialization routines so as opposed to redefining them every time I simply call $class->SUPER::new(@_) as well as do things specific to that animal.

With this being said every time an animal is initialized it goes through it's superclasses' initialization routines.  There are hundreds of animals and these are run hundreds of times.  It's not too big of a problem.

These animals are smart however and know how to use the LWP::UserAgent web browser.  In order to access the internet they must log into a web page and set their session cookies.  They all share the same login and would like to share the same browser.  In my current implementation the login routines are part of the superclass's new method.  This means when an animal is initialized this runs and the animal logs in.  As I said I have hundreds of animals and do not want to fire off hundreds of POST requests.  I would like to somehow fire off the login routine once and make it part of the super class.  Each animal can then access the "shared" web browser by doing $self->{'ua'}.

I hope this explains it, I am not sure what this OOP term is called.

**TLDR for those who don't like Animals**

I have a login routine in the superclass that creates an LWP::UserAgent, logs in, and sets session cookies.  The subclasses can all share one login.  I do not want to have to fire off hundreds of POST requests to log in for each subclass.  I would like to somehow log in once and share the prepared $ua object wil all subclasses.

Comment: Did not noticed the question sign in this text ;) But yes, you can easily implement this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to approach this:

### 1. Package variables

Not each animal instance has an UA, but the UA is part of being an Animal. You can initialize the UA on startup. The animals can access the UA via an accessor, or a variable:

```
package Animal;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

sub ua { $ua }
```

and then

```
my $ua = $self->ua();
```

or

```
package Animal;

our $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
```

and then

```
my $ua = $Animal::ua;
```

Technical terms for this are *class variable*, or in languages like Java *static method* or *static variable*.

Java translations:

```
class Animal {
  private static LWP.UserAgent ua = new LWP.UserAgent();
  public static LWP.UserAgent getUa() { return ua }
  ...
}
```

and

```
class Animal {
  public static LWP.UserAgent ua = new LWP.UserAgent();
  ...
}
```

### 2. `state` variables

In newer Perls (>= v5.10?) you can declare variables with `state`. They declare lexical variables. The variable is initialized once during the lifetime of the program, not every time the statement is executed (as it would be with `my`).

```
use feature 'state';
package Animal;
sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  state $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  bless { ua => $ua, %args } => $class;
}
```

and then

```
my $ua = $self->{ua};
```

It may be useful to use a `do` block to perform wider intialization

```
state $ua = do {
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  ...;
  $ua;
};
```

or to offload initialization into a sub: `state $ua = make_ua();`

If you have to target earlier perls, you can enclose the `new` sub inside a seperate scope, and declare the variable there as a lexical for similar effect:

```
package Animal;

{
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    bless { ua => $ua, %args } => $class;
  }
}
```

The only difference here is *when* the UA is initialized. (And, of course, the number of irritating braces.) The intialization can be deffered, as [Len Jaffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40285/len-jaffe) mentioned:

```
package Animal;

{
  my $ua; # just declare scope here
  sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    $ua ||= LWP::UserAgent->new;  # $ua is false until initialized
    bless { ua => $ua, %args } => $class;
  }
}
```

Because objects are references, all animals will get the same UA.

Especially in C/C++, this is also called a *static variable*. The `state` modifier could be seen as a non-OO singleton constructor.

Comment: There's also the Singleton pattern implementation in which the constructor calls LWP::UA->new() but 'caches' the reference in class variable: $ua ||= LWP::UA->new()

Comment: @LenJaffe Yes, one could go full OO and implement the actual singleton pattern. But, using `state` is the *perlish* way to go (I'd say).

Comment: Why would the class variable be undef after having been instantiated by the first constructor?

Comment: I read the orig version of your comment, where the `my` was still present

Comment: force of habit. sorry. quickly noted and corrected :-) Your answer is good.

Comment: This is a great answer - especially the comparison with Java.  But I think it could be improved and made more complete by expanding the examples.  Using globals like ```our $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();``` and then initializing parent objects in a subclass with ```my $ua = $Animal::ua;``` is fairly straightforward. However, the example code from the first part of the response ("Package variables") where you suggest ```sub ua { $ua }``` and ```my $ua = $self->ua();``` isn't complete enough for a new or intermediate user of perl to test your examples. If you did that I'd up vote this answer :)